# Javascript hangman: trouble with replacing blanks with correct letters

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm having trouble with a specific part of this game. These are my initial variables:

```
var words = ["sugar","banana","hulk"];
var guessLeft = 12;
var wrongGuess = [];
var hiddenWord = [];
var hiddenWordText = document.getElementById("hiddenword-text");
var chosenWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
```

So far it's correctly picking a random word from my array, and replacing them with underlines with the same length as the chosen word. Here's how I did that:

```
for (i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++) {
    hiddenWord.push("_");
    hiddenWordText.textContent = hiddenWord.join(" ");
}
```

Now, where I'm having trouble is with when it figures out if my guess matched the letter, how to replace the correct underline index with the letter guessed.

This is what I have so far and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. Does anyone have any tips or can you guide me in the right direction?

```
document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    var userGuess = event.key;

    if (chosenWord.indexOf(userGuess) >= 0){
        for (var i = 0; i < wordLength; i++){
            if (chosenWord[i] == userGuess){
                hiddenWord[i] == userGuess;

                hiddenWordText.textContent = hiddenWord[i] + hiddenWord;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        guessLeft = guessLeft - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: When I correctly guess a letter of the word it adds another underline right next to the existing underline instead of displaying the correct letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your code

Use `=` instead of `==` for variable assignment

Replace `textContext` of `hiddenWordText` with `hiddenWord.join(" ")` after the loop, in which the correctly guessed word has been revealed. Previously you keep replacing the `textContext` at every loop iteration, which will ignore the match found in the previous iterations

```
if (chosenWord.indexOf(userGuess) >= 0){
    for (var i = 0; i < chosenWord.length; i++){
        if (chosenWord[i] == userGuess){
            hiddenWord[i] = userGuess;
        }
    }
    hiddenWordText.textContent = hiddenWord.join(" ");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It really was that simple, it works now :)

Comment: One tip for these kind of issues, if you are not sure where did it go wrong, try printing with `console.log()` at every step or loop iteration for the relevant variables. Then you can identify the issue and see which part of the logic is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to figure out which underscores in the `hiddenWord` need to be replaced with the true letter, you might instead have an array of letters that have been picked so far, put them in a negative character set in a regular expression, and from the true input word, replace all characters *not* in that set with an underscore. For example:

```js
const chosenWord = 'banana';

const guesses = [];
// when a user guesses a letter, push it to guesses:
// example, user guesses "a" and "b":
guesses.push('a');
guesses.push('b');

// then, when you need to display the partially-filled-in word:
const pattern = new RegExp(
  '[^' + guesses.join('') + ']', 'g'
);

// in this case, the pattern will look like:
//    [^ab]
// which means, match any characters that are not "a" nor "b"


// Replace all characters that are neither "a" nor "b" with an underscore:
const wordToDisplay = chosenWord.replace(pattern, '_');
console.log(wordToDisplay);
// hiddenWordText.textContent = wordToDisplay;
```